# How to obtain List from executing stored procedure that needs parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dapper

Can someone tell me the syntax for doing this? I can't find anything on https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Here's what I have so far:

```
using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
    Debug.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["max-files-limit"]));
    param.Add("@NumOfFiles", Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["max-files-limit"]));
    con.Open();
    IList<AsyncFileProcessingQueue> fileList = SqlMapper.Query<AsyncFileProcessingQueue>(con, "GetMostRecentFileStatus", param).ToList();
    return fileList.ToList();
}
```

I'm getting this error,

```
Procedure or function 'GetMostRecentFileStatus' expects parameter '@NumOfFiles', which was not supplied.
```

`GetMostRecentFileStatus` is a stored Procedure. I don't know if this might be the issue. but I was thinking that maybe it doesn't know I'm using a stored procedure?

I saw an example like this

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); 

int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
int c = p.Get<int>("@c");
```

But how can I get a List instead of outputs?

The stored procedure looks like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMostRecentFileStatus
(
    @NumOfFiles INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT TOP (@NumOfFiles) Filename, Status
FROM AsyncFileProcessingQueue
ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pass the parameters with the Query method.

This should work!

```
int numberOfFiles=2;
var q = @"exec GetMostRecentFileStatus @NumOfFiles";
using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    return con.Query<YourFileTypeDto>(q, new { @NumOfFiles=numberOfFiles }).ToList();
}
```

You can replace the hardcoded value of `numberOfFiles` variable with your an argumenet value of your method/read from somewhere

Comment: Mmm, I will try that, so how does the dynamic parameter work then? I thought dynamic parameter itself was a parameter object :(

Comment: The second parameter you are passing is an announymous object with the parameter name/values.

Comment: Mmmm, it failed at ToList() saying "int doesn't contain definition for ToList()" and no extension method "ToList()"

Comment: Sorry ! Try this version.

Comment: I finally got it. I needed the commandType = StoredProcedure.
`return con.Query<AsyncFileProcessingQueue>("GetMostRecentFileStatus", new { NumOfFiles = limit }, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();`

Comment: @ygongdev minor note: AsList avoids an extra alloc

Comment: Oh interesting, if the return type is already a list, ToList allocates a new List and deep copy the value over?

In that case, is it like a wrapper that checks the data structure type before calling ToList()?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int numFiles = ...
var list = connection.Query<SomeType>(
      "GetMostRecentFileStatus",
      new { NumberOfFiles = numFiles },
     commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the equivalent in Tortuga Chain

```
static Tortuga.Chain.SqlServerDataSource DS = new Tortuga.Chain.SqlServerDataSource (connectionString);

var fileCount = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["max-files-limit"]);
var fileList = DS.Procedure("GetMostRecentFileStatus", new { @NumOfFiles =  fileCount }).ToCollection<AsyncFileProcessingQueue>().Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately, I'm not using Tortuga Chain atm :(